# Ubuntu 18.04: "sudo -H nautilus" causing system problem detected

Tags: permissions, nautilus

I am using Ubuntu 18.04 and I wanted to access a directory which only root could read or write to. I read somewhere I could launch nautilus as root with this command: `sudo -H nautilus` which opened a file explorer which still didn't have root permissions. This is the error that came up in the console:

```
$ sudo -H nautilus
Gtk-Message: 11:26:52.751: GtkDialog mapped without a transient parent. This is discouraged.

(nautilus:3453): Gtk-CRITICAL **: 11:26:52.752: gtk_widget_show: assertion 'GTK_IS_WIDGET (widget)' failed

** (nautilus:3453): CRITICAL **: 11:26:52.752: setup_side_pane_width: assertion 'priv->sidebar != NULL' failed

** (nautilus:3453): WARNING **: 11:26:52.925: Unable to get contents of the bookmarks file: Error opening file /root/.gtk-bookmarks: No such file or directory

** (nautilus:3453): WARNING **: 11:26:52.925: Unable to get contents of the bookmarks file: Error opening file /root/.gtk-bookmarks: No such file or directory
```

I then found out I could reach the directory just by directing a normal file explorer to `admin://<absolute path of directory>`. That did it, but now every time I log into my account there's a popup showing up after a couple of minutes saying `System problem detected`. I am guessing it has something to do with that `sudo -H nautilus` I ran. I didn't reboot in between the two solutions so I can't really say.

PS: That directory I wanted to access was one created by an unfinished `photorec` I did to recover a file. For some reason I wasn't able to delete that directory, named `recup_dir.1`, because I didn't have permission.

Comment: It is a good idea to do admin tasks with command lines (in a terminal window). In this case you can try `sudo rm -r /path-to-the-directory/recup_dir.1`; Maybe you could not remove the directory directly because there are files in it, but `rm -r` will remove also subdirectories and files.

Comment: The crash report(s) that generate the `System problem detected` error message are located in the `/var/crash/` directory. Usually these error messages disappear after a while, and you can also find the specific crash report that is generating the error message in `/var/crash/` and delete it with `sudo rm path/to/crash/report/file`

Comment: Thanks @karel that solved my problem! I don't see how the suggested duplicate could solve my problem, which is getting rid of the error message on startup.